# Natural Language measure of obfuscation

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

I have some experience with sentiment analysis in natural language processing, but want to learn some new algorithms and techniques for a project I am working on. In particular, I am interested in a measure of how much a text is ``obfuscated'', such as the one provided as a black-box by http://www.blablameter.com/

What would be a good place to start learning about such algorithms?

Thanks!

Comment: These papers could be of some help: + [Using A Probabilistic Model Of Context To Detect Word Obfuscation](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/ballison/pdf/sanaz_lrec08.pdf) + [Using Common-Sense knowledge-base for
Detecting Word Obfuscation in Adversarial
Communication](https://www.iiitd.edu.in/~ashish/BDA2014.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

These sort of algorithms often predate machine learning and have their roots in the linguistic community. A commonly used such measure of "clarity"  is the [Gunning Fog Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunning_fog_index), which estimates the years of formal education a person needs to understand the text on the first reading.

An alternative is the [Flesch–Kincaid readability test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch%E2%80%93Kincaid_readability_tests) that quantifies   how difficult a passage in English is to understand.

I have seen both examples above (and others) being used in NLP problems. The short answer to your question is "*search in the linguistics domain rather than the machine learning community to start learning about such algorithms*".